# Double data maintenance with RecyclerView and database

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm working with the Room library. When I fetch some data, I get a List of Entities, that I present in a RecyclerView. The user is able to delete elements presented in that RecyclerView, which is implemented with a `@Delete` method in the DataAccessObject.

In order to also remove the deleted element from the RecyclerView, I also have to remove the element from the List of Entities mentioned earlier. And this what I don't like. I have to manually keep two data structures in sync.

Is there a way to link the RecyclerView directly to the a certain set of data in the database? Without an intermediate data structure I have to sync manually, thus when I delete an element in the database, this is immediately reflected in the RecyclerView.Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room supports [observable queries](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable). So instead of returning list of entities in your dao object, return `LiveData<List<Entity>>` or one of the [supported RxJava2 types](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava) and you'll get updates every time data is changed in the db, e.g. when item is removed.

It's convenient to use this api with [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter), which wraps [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer.html) to calculate diff on every list update, so you'll get `RecyclerView` animations for free.